# shared memory and fork

Tags: perl, shared-memory, fork

I'm using fork to create 9 processes, and I want it to run : 4 times print "a chosen.", 3 times print "b chosen", and 2 times print "c chosen". For that I need to decrease a counter for each running case, and I need to use shared memory,but don't know how, can you help?

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl5.14.1

my $all_running = 9;            #2+3+4
my @times_to_run = (4, 3, 2);
my (@children, @non_empty_cells);

# make an array which will save the indexes of cells in @times_to_run which aren't empty

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@times_to_run); $i++) {
  if ($times_to_run[$i] != 0) {
    push(@non_empty_cells, $i);
  }
}

while ($all_running > 0) {      #run 5 times

  my $pid = fork();

  if (!defined($pid)) {
    print("Fork Failed\n");
  }
  elsif ($pid > 0) {

    #parent
    push(@children, $pid);
    sleep(0.5);
  }
  else {  # child

    # pick a non-empty cell

    my $random_ = int(rand(@non_empty_cells));

    if ($non_empty_cells[$random_] == 0) {
      print "a chosen\n";
      $times_to_run[0]--;
      print "now $times_to_run[0]\n";

    }
    elsif ($non_empty_cells[$random_] == 1) {
      print "b chosen \n";
      $times_to_run[1]--;
      print "now $times_to_run[1]\n";

    }
    else {
      print "c chosen\n";
      $times_to_run[2]--;
      print "now $times_to_run[2]\n";

    }

    # update non empty-cells array

    @non_empty_cells = ();

    for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@times_to_run); $i++) {
      if ($times_to_run[$i] != 0) {
        push(@non_empty_cells, $i);
      }
    }

  # print "now empty cells is : ".scalar(@non_empty_cells)."\n\n";
    exit 0;
  }

  $all_running--;
}

foreach (@children) {
  my $tmp = waitpid($_, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without doing so much , just kill one  process in each if condition. So after 4 processes prints "a chosen" , 1 gets killed so "b chosen will be printed 3 times". you need to kill the processes using their PID's.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want shared memory, there are many ways to get it: [`shmget`,](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shmget.html) [`IPC::Sharable`,](http://search.cpan.org/~msouth/IPC-Shareable-0.61/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm) [`forks::shared`,](http://search.cpan.org/~rybskej/forks-0.34/lib/forks/shared.pm) ...

But in your case, this is definitely overkill. You could simply assign whatever you need to one variable before forking, like this:

```
my @test = qw( a b c );

for my $test (@test) {
    my $pid  = fork;
    if (!$pid) {
        say $test;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Or, to remain closer to your example:

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my @test = shuffle (('a chosen') x 4, ('b chosen') x 3, ('c chosen') x 2);

for my $test (@test) {
    my $pid  = fork;
    if (!$pid) {
        say $test;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to pick one randomly each time ( a b or c). That is why I need a counter that will count how many already were printed from each one.

Comment: @user3595059, Do you *need* the randomness to occur inside the child process? Because it's just easier to `shuffle` the array (or use `rand`, if you like it better) before forking.

Comment: ye, you are right :)
I did the random before, and made it without the shared memory. Thanks!